# Push A List of Objects Into an Array Using jQuery (Or Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$=jQuery.noConflict();
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //returns an array of image links
    // ["http://velnikolic.com/gallery/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file4741298583098-1-150x150.jpg", "http://velnikolic.com/gallery/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file9221293737060-150x150.jpg", "http://velnikolic.com/gallery/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file4741298583098-150x150.jpg"]
    var images = <?php echo json_encode($images); ?>;
    console.log(images);
    src = [];
    data = {}

    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        data = {
            src: images[i] 
        };

        src.push(data);
        console.log(data);
        //Data should equal [{src : imageurlxxx}, {src :imgurlxxdd}, {src :imgurlxxdd} ]}
    }
});//close
```

The above code should loop through the images array and push it into an object with `src` as the key, then it should push this object into an array and reiterate. The problem is that the object is overwritten in the array because they all have the same key.

Comment: Actually - data should only equal to an object with one key, and not to what you are looking for. The `src` variable should have what you are looking for, and it will be after the `for` loop.

Comment: `var src = $.map(images, x => {src : x})`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code does exactly what you are looking for, but you checked the wrong variable:

```js
var images = ["A", "B", "C"]
console.log(images);
src = [];
data = {}
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  data = {
    src: images[i] 
  };
  // Here data is an object with 1 key only.

  src.push(data);
}
// Here - after the loop - the src variable will contain all of the values that you want.
console.log(src);
```

And if you are looking for an ES6 solution you can use this one:

```js
var images = ["A", "B", "C"];
var src = images.map((img) => { return {src: img} });
console.log(src);
```

Comment: @TxRegex the images are already javascript-object, and not a string

Answer (score 1):

```
function getImages() {
    var images = <?php echo json_encode($images); ?>;
    return images.map(function (image) {
        return { src: image };
    }
};
```

Assuming you are using this on a php site and $images is set, getImages() returns something like this:

```
 [
    {src: "http://velnikolic.com/gallery/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file4741298583098-150x150.jpg"},
    {src: "http://velnikolic.com/gallery/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file9221293737060-150x150.jpg"}, 
    {src: "http://velnikolic.com/gallery/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file4741298583098-150x150.jpg"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Data should equal [{src : imageurlxxx}, {src :imgurlxxdd}, {src :imgurlxxdd} ]}
data = $.map(images, (image) => { src: image })
```

If i'm reading what you want right, you just need to map your image urls into the array like you want them.

Comment: There is no need for jquery map here, you can use Array.map function (you can check the example in my answer)